# Slow login and blinking cursor on logout after upgrade 21.10 -> 22.04

Tags: upgrade, login, 22.04

After upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04, I've started experiencing 2 problems:

1. Logging in takes more than 20 seconds but only after locking, not so much at first login. Previously it took less than a second.
2. Logging out causes a black screen with a blinking cursor for about 30 seconds after which the login screen appears as normal.

Could these be related? How do I debug this?

Comment: Same symptoms here, but no use of `fprint` as mentioned in Stefan Garlonta's answer. It must be a more general bug?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
This can happen if you have `fprint` installed, but you don't use fingerprint because it doesn't work.

The fprint PAM module then waits for the timeout, which by default is 10 secs.

For me, it worked to delete the following line from `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10 # debug
```

Like that, your system will just use normal login without trying to read your fingerprint with a sensor that is not supported.

Hope this helps!